# Is there an equivalent of the C function mbsinvalid on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, aix

Porting a C application from AIX to Linux - does anyone know if there's an equivalent of the mbsinvalid() function on Linux?

From the AIX pages:

"The mbsinvalid subroutine examines the string pointed to by the S parameter to determine the validity of characters. The LC_CTYPE category affects the behavior of the mbsinvalid subroutine."

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.basetechref/doc/basetrf1/mbsinvalid.htm

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `mbstowcs` with NULL destination pointer:

> If dest is NULL, n is ignored, and the conversion proceeds as above, except that the converted wide characters are not written out  to  memory, and that no length limit exists.
>
> ....
>
> 1. An invalid multibyte sequence has been encountered.  In this case (size_t) -1 is returned.

(from [mbstowcs man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mbstowcs)).

That is, the result of `(size_t)-1` means there was an invalid multibyte sequence.

Comment: Brilliant! Looks like that'll do it!